# SyntaxError: Invalid Syntax in python when trying to use tarfile.open() on a .tgz file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to view the contents of a .tgz file. I tried this code, based on the tutorial at http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/tarfile/:

```
import tarfile

tar = tarfile.open("exampleTar.tgz","r")

print tar.getnames()
```

But I get an error that says `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`, with a `^` symbol pointing at the 'r' in the last line.

What is wrong, and how do I fix it?

Comment: `print` is a function in python-3.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Print](http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/whatsnew/3.0.html#print-is-a-function) is function in python 3.x.

```
import tarfile

tar = tarfile.open("exampleTar.tgz","r")

print(tar.getnames())
```